# Ajustar el tema en tiempo real

Tags: android-studio, color, theme

Con el siguiente método cambio los colores del tema de la app a través de botones, sin embargo aun me falta como asignar el nuevo valor del color Accent (ejemplo del cambio checkbox).

```
   public void AjusteColor(String primaryDark, String Accent){
this.window=getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor(primaryDark));
        window.setNavigationBarColor(Color.parseColor(primaryDark));
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(primaryDark)));

    }
```

Lo realizo desde un menu

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.cerrarsesion) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.Main_logout2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        }
        if (id == R.id.verde) {
            String primaryDark="#008577";
            String Accent="#4CAF50";

            AjusteColor(primaryDark,Accent);
        }
        if (id == R.id.rosa) {
            String primaryDark="#F5E91E63";
            String Accent="#E9F1598A";

            AjusteColor(primaryDark,Accent);
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: Dentro del método AjusteColor() a que elementos le asignarías el AccentColor?

Comment: A unos floatinbutton que estan en ciertos fragment, y un naviggationbar